# Do closed questions no longer show up on the front page?

Tags: support

After a recent question was closed, I've repeatedly had to search for it to find it. Do closed questions no longer show up on the front page?

Comment: Questions with -5 score don't show up on the main page (but they do on the active questions tab). Could that explain your issue?

Comment: @DoubleAA, hmm, it seems the question I'm thinking of does not show up under other tabs, but only if I go to my inbox.

Comment: It's not the 6th question here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active ?

Comment: @DoubleAA, hmm, it is.  I see what you did there.  I clicked the "active" link from the main page, because both the Questions tab and the Active tab were highlighted, so I didn't think more was needed.  But when I first clicked on Questions and then on Active, it gave me your view.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closed questions can still appear on the main page (you can currently see one on the main view here on meta), but there is a vote threshold below which questions do not appear there.  (I believe that threshold is either -4 or -5.)

As @DoubleAA said in a comment, the question is still there in other views, and you can still navigate to it from anywhere that it's linked (asker's profile, any answerer's profile, your profile if you've commented, etc).

Comment: This answers my question, thanks!